# A simple message room

Tags: web-hosting, php, web-development

Can anyone recommend a simple message room (not chat room) which I can use for a private communication between my users.

My idea: to grant some users (2-3 at the most) a specific privilege to talk privately in a message room. none of them would be administrator there.

I need such features:
- admin panel for adding users allowed to post messages in room
- room invisible to anyone except users
- filtering not-allowed words
- Ajax-enabled so that replies appear immediately
- other message room features

I have a linux hosting so PHP message room would be the best option.

I thought of using a forum for this, but it's too much work as a forum is public by nature and I need something **private by nature**.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend PHP/AJAX for chat rooms. For a close to real-time chat there are going to be an excessive amount of requests to your server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

phpBB is open source and you can easily make forums private, very easily.
http://www.phpbb.com/

Here is how to set permissions on forums
http://www.phpbb.com/support/documentation/3.0/quickstart/quick_permissions.php

Comment: I thought of it. But it's a forum. Would it be ugly if I have dozens of private topics or rooms?

Comment: Also, is phpBB ajax-enabled? I think you have to refresh to see new replies

Comment: This may help http://www.phpbb.com/customise/db/mod/mchat_new_version/

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're asking for is something more like crytocat which you can find via the chrome webstore. I also believe it can be included in a website. its something of a hybrid between a forum and a chat room... think of the old dial in BBC.

I was going to link to it but  outside of the webstore (free by the way) searches for cryptocat bring up a router like device that auto hacks wifi.